# What does the spring boot /health top status: UP indicates

Tags: spring, spring-boot

There is a health endpoint which indicates the status of other health indicatiors and as well the main status. My question is:

Is the top `status: "UP"` just a summary of other health indicators, or it actually can indicate `"DOWN"` for some other reason? 
Is this the actual application health?

```
{
  status: "UP",

  jms: {
    status: "UP",
    provider: "ActiveMQ"
  },

  diskSpace: {
    status: "UP",
    total: 255179702272,
    free: 78310952960,
    threshold: 10485760
  },

  db: {
    status: "UP",
    database: "Oracle",
    hello: "Hello"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply aggregates (via the configured [`HealthAggregator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator.html)) the statuses of all the configured [`HealthIndicator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthIndicator.html)s.

You can provide a custom implementation if you wanted it to do something else.